# I wan to duplicate elements of one column to another but with one element skipped & ignoring the last one as it generates error

Tags: pandas, for-loop, data-science

```
for i in range(len(nifty['Pivot'])):
  nifty.p[i] = nifty.Pivot[i+1]
```

I want to skip the last elemnt & want to keep the first elemnt of p as empty element
Error:

```
ValueError: 200 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


KeyError: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

That's your error `Pivot[i+1]`, say if `len(nifty['Pivot'])=200` then at `i=199`, `i+1=200`, and `nifty.Pivot[200]` will fail since the maximum index allowed is `199` (Python is `0` indexed)

I think you want `nifty['p'] = nifty['Pivot'].shift(-1)`

Comment: It gives error 
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'

Comment: @AksharRastogi no `for` loop. Replace your two lines with just what I suggested.

Comment: Thankyou it worked @QuangHoang but I want the first element of p be empty & from there the second element  of 'nifty['p']' filled by the **first element** of 'nifty['Pivot]'  & so on